# How can you get appcelerator titanium studio to show uncaught runtime errors in the console log?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

It seems like at runtime all uncaught errors in appcelerator get swallowed by the titanium IDE and never show up in the console log.  How can you get rid of this behavior and make sure the errors show up there?

Comment: are you debugging on device or with the simulator? iOS or Android?

Comment: iOS and using the emulator.  I'm looking at the console log in the Titanium IDE

Comment: So when you run your app and you hit an un caught exception you don't get a red line in console showing what the red screen of death showed?

Comment: What titanium SDK version are you running?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have set the correct log level. Read more at appcelerator's [Blog - Changing the log level in TiStudio](http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2011/08/changing-the-log-level-in-tistudio/)

As stated in the article, `Trace` will give you more details.